# How to prioritise running broadcast job over listener job in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to broadcast a model and then delete it. So I created an event that broadcast the model and a listener to delete the broadcasted model. The problem is sometimes the DeleteListener job runs before broadcasting job and I will receive a model not found error. Both broadcasting and DeleteListener should be queued and I can't use ShouldBroadcastNow interface.

Comment: You should share more details on issue. When you broadcast that model and that listener you mentioned, what event it is listening? If those are coupled tasks and have to run in a certain way on queue maybe you can check Laravel's job batching feature.

Comment: @UğurArıcı Thank you for you attention. I have an event that broadcasts the mode and the event has a listener that deletes the model.